# Places Folders Open in Archive Manager

Tags: archive

Am relatively new to Ubuntu. Currently running 10.10, which was an upgrade from 10.4, which was an upgrade from 9.10, which was a fresh install.

Have never compressed anything in Ubuntu, but because I wanted to use the contents of a large folder on a Windows machine, I installed 7zip. Using Places, I navigated to the folder I wanted to compress, right-clicked, chose Compress, selected 7-zip and started the compression. This took many minutes to complete (the final 7z file is over 2.2 GB), but when I copied it to the windows machine, 7-zip handles it fine.

However, now when I open Places, the Home Folder, User folder, Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos and Downloads all open the Archive Manager which gives an error message that it "Could not create the archive" because the "Archive type not supported."

If I open Places/Computer choose the usr folder from places on the left and right-click/Properties on any of the folders, Music for instance, there is no place to change the "open with."

Anyone know how to get this working again.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have problem compressing file? Or do you have problem with 7zip format? Or the problem is to open some file types with a predefined application?

Comment: I have the same problem and am surprised that this question is still not answered.
I think it is explained by op very clearly.
The problem is with the "Places menu". Home folder and other folders actually open Archive manager with an error message, instead of the designated folder. Only item that works is Computer, and from that window it is possible to open Home folder etc. normally.

Anyone knows how to fix Places menu shortcuts so it opens folder windows as it should instead of archive manager?

pic here:
http://www4.pic-upload.de/24.01.11/1qypag42gj41.jpg

@maco: your answer might

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click -> Open with Other Application  (just like you did before), and select File Browser.  Make sure the checkbox at the bottom that says

> Remember this application for "folder" files

is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer I found after 3 hours of frustration!!  Works great!!

```
 gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Change the line starting:

```
inode/directory=
```

to read:

```
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;*
```

Comment: +1 for GNOME and probably Unity. For MATE the correct line is `inode/directory=caja-folder-handler.desktop;`. Not sure what the asterisk does (inherit associations from more generic type?) but it works well without for me. Note that I had to change the line in `[Default Applications]`, there is also a section `[Added Associations]`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how my settings got changed. I did play with Archive Manager yesterday.

My configuration: Ubuntu Mate 15.04 (Mate Desktop Environment 1.8.2)

My solution: Update `~/.config/mimeapps.list` under sections **[Default Applications]** and **[Added Associations]**

from

```
inode/directory=engrampa.desktop
```

to

```
inode/directory=caja.desktop
```