# Places in Ubuntu opening with wrong application

Tags: nautilus, firefox, filemanager

*Places* in Ubuntu specifically *Home*, *Documents*, *Music*, *Pictures* and *Downloads* are opening in my browser.

Eg. If I click *Documents* then it opens on Firefox. How to operate Ubuntu normally again?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/6886/46531)?